# atexit alternative for ipython

Tags: ipython, python-3.5, ipython-magic

python has [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html) module to register functions to run prior to closing of the interpreter. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618769/atexit-function-is-not-called-when-exiting-the-script-using-ipython) nicely why atexit is not called.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative for `ipython` to register a function prior to exiting something which has been run with `%run <name>`? Ideally I would like to create a decorator which works registers in either 
module depending on the interpreter.

Comment: There is not something that fires specifically after `%run`, but you could either [define a custom magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html) to do `%run` plus some action, or [provide a post_run_cell callback](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html) to run after each input is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Thomas K for the good comment. In case he writes an answer I'll accept his. Otherwise this piece of code might benefit somebody else:

```
# exit_register runs at the end of ipython %run or the end of the python interpreter
try:
    def exit_register(fun, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Decorator that registers at post_execute. After its execution it
        unregisters itself for subsequent runs. """
        def callback():
            fun()
            ip.events.unregister('post_execute', callback)
        ip.events.register('post_execute', callback)


    ip = get_ipython()
except NameError:
    from atexit import register as exit_register


@exit_register
def callback():
    print('I\'m done!')


print('Running')
```

Comment: This works great.  One thing to add.  `atexit.register` can take arguments and keyword arguments.  Consider changing `exit_register` to allow this via: `def exit_register(fun, *args, **kwargs)` and `fun(*args, **kwargs)`.