# Python atexit function is not called on Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder, atexit

I'm working on Spyder IDE, version 3.0.0. My python version is 2.7.12.
For some reason, the atexit mechanism doesn't work on this particular IDE.

---

**Code**

```
import atexit

def done():
    print '2'

atexit.register(done)
print '1'
```

---

**Result**

When I run the script in PyCharm or from Windows cmd, it prints:

```
1
2
```

When I run it from Spyder, done function is not being called, and 2 is not printed. The final result is:

```
1
```

---

Does someone knows why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you gave would never print `1` or `2`...

Comment: @linusg, thanks, it was an older version. I updated the question

Comment: As far I can tell, `atextit` only calls registered functions when the program terminates with no error code, so make sure it's not aborted or killed in an abrupt way.

Comment: I think `atexit` takes place when Spyder is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use atexit.register(), you can call atexit._run_exitfuncs, as in answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21634308/6669602

(Or you can restart the kernel)