# Why does callback not called which is defined with @atexit.register at sys.exit in Python?

Tags: python, atexit

Description:

I wonder that why does callback not called which is defined with @atexit.register at sys.exit in Python?

---

Code 1:

```
import atexit
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    @atexit.register
    def Func1():
        print("Func1!!!")
    sys.exit(0)
```

---

Output:

[Output of Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAxun.png)

---

IDE:

Spyder in Anaconda Navigator with IPython 8.12.0

---

Interpreter:

Python 3.11.4

---

Any replies will be very appreciated. Thank you.

What I have tried:

Google and take a glance at:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Comment: Your exact code works fine for me.  It could be an odd side effect of IPython.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tim Roberts, I don't think so, I think I misunderstand the atexit module.

Answer (score 1):

I finally know why it does Output nothing.

Sorry for my misunderstanding of atexit module.

The following website in Ref section says that callback which is
defined in atexit.register will be called iff once the Python interpreter exits.

However, in Spyder Console. When finishing execution of script, the Python interpreter does NOT exit.

---

Ref:

[atexit function is not called when exiting the script using Ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618769/atexit-function-is-not-called-when-exiting-the-script-using-ipython)